# Facebook Login Redirect URI pointed to my cloud server, but only localhost works? So close to production

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am finished my website and I am so close to production, please I need help! :O
My website has Facebook login that has been configured for my AWS cloud server. I removed all references to localhost in the Facebook App settings, and yet localhost still works and my production server does not! I get the following 2 error messages:

Error1:

> URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not
>   whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and
>   Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth
>   Redirect URIs.

Error 2: (I get multiple of these)

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more
>   of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match
>   the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of
>   one of the App's domains. The Facebook App settings is the same for
>   both localhost and AWS. However, there is no mention of localhost in
>   my whitelist, valid callback URIs..etc The settings are tuned for AWS
>   and yet localhost works and AWS fails!

I have looked extensively online for a solution and I have tried different URI combinations of http://myWebsite.com, www.myWebsite.com, www.myWebsite.com/oauthcallback.html..etc with no avail.

This is what my javascript login code looks like. I dont really understand where/how to define my redirect URL. Could someone please explain?

```
FB.login(function(response){
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        console.log('Logged in!');
    } else {
        console.log('not logged in');
    }
});
```

Finally, here's what my Facebook App Settings looks like:

[image]
[image]

I have also added my cloud server's IP address to the "Server IP Whitelist".
Could the `/#/map` in the url be somehow affecting the URI?

Does anyone know what is happening, and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I may have spotted a typo in your "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs" section. Specifically, I think you're missing the first 'p' in idpresponse:

Correct: https://.auth..amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse

Incorrect: https://.auth..amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idresponse